Why simultaneous reprojecting enables when exporting raster in QGIS?
At QGIS 3.34.13 I have an .sdat (Saga) raster file, single-band, 8-bit unsigned integer, pixel size (meters) 30, -30, CRS ESRI:102039 - USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version.  The data is located in Washington State, USA.
I need to:

reproject to EPSG:26910 - NAD83/UTM zone 10N
convert to a .tif format.

If I use the Raster > Projections > Warp tool, the output pixel size is 29.954..., 29.954... I don't know why the size isn't the original 30, -30 value, but it is sufficiently close to my needs. I then Export > Save As... to a .tif file, and the output retains the 29.954-pixel size.
However, I wondered if I could forego the Projection step and Export the original .sdat file to .tif, while simultaneously changing the output CRS to the desired EPSG:26910, as shown in the screenshot. But, the Export window defaults to a 20.0164, 37.5832 pixel size. Although I can override those dimensions, I'm asking: Why does the Export tool default to this rectangular pixel size?


Having a look at the source code would be the best source for information, but it is also possible to make a guess.
First imagine that the source pixel in ESRI:102039 is a 100x100m sized polygon
POLYGON ((
        -2254100 2209300, 
        -2254100 2209400, 
        -2254000 2209400, 
        -2254000 2209300, 
        -2254100 2209300
    ))

Convert each corner point into EPSG:26910
gdaltransform -t_srs epsg:26910 -s_srs ESRI:102039
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
-2254100 2209300
500113.680591723 4427717.14670217 0
-2254100 2209400
500085.405947454 4427812.23280923 0
-2254000 2209400
500182.233090298 4427839.99913277 0
-2254000 2209300
500210.507784263 4427744.91303851 0

The result is a rotated, almost square polygon

However, in raster images the pixels are oriented horizontally and vertically and the result must be resampled. What if the resampling is based on the re-projected coordinates of the lower-left and top-right corners of the pixel?

I do not know if that QGIS tool calculates the default output pixel size with this simple method, but at least the pixel shapes match.
Notice that because of the rotation the end raster must be resampled anyway. Maintaining the original pixel size would not keep the original pixels. But I would say that in this case the GDAL tool selects more reasonable default pixel size. Fortunately you do not need to use the defaults but you can set the output resolution as you wish.
